# How to Solve This error (Server Is Busy The record was saved. However, the data could not be displayed because the server is busy)

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016, security-roles

How do I solve this error that occurs after assigning a record to another user

[image: Error]

> Server Is Busy
>
> The record was saved. However, the data could not be displayed because
>   the server is busy. Click Try Again to try to display the data now, or
>   click Cancel to continue to work. If you click Cancel, you can try
>   opening the record later.

Comment: Anything in the Download Log?

Comment: @Daryl <Message>SecLib::AccessCheckEx failed. Returned hr = -2147187962, ObjectID: f84f609e-31dd-e911-80da-005056aaf318, OwnerId: ed33ce4c-7da1-e911-80da-005056aaf318,  OwnerIdType: 8 and CallingUser: ed33ce4c-7da1-e911-80da-005056aaf318. ObjectTypeCode: 10022, objectBusinessUnitId: 3f88c482-9d8c-e711-80c0-005056aaf318, AccessRights: ReadAccess

Comment: That error is a rights issue, totally unrelated to server is busy

Comment: any recommendation from your side to check to solve this error ??

Comment: My best guess is an infinite loop.  Turn off as many workflows and plug-ins as you can and see if the error remains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the security role of the old owner is just having user-level read access, this error will be thrown - since that record is owned by the new owner after the Assign operation.

> The error message is bit incorrect here. The error was because the user had User Level Read Access to the record or (Entity to be specific) and on saving the record, we had one of our real-time workflow being triggered which was assigning this record to another user. And on assignment, the record being getting assigned to another user, the user who had created\saved the record was losing the access to it.

[Reference](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/nishantranaweblog/posts/server-is-busy-the-record-was-saved-however-the-data-could-not-be-displayed-because-the-server-is-busy-error-in-dynamics-365)